# Updating entities in bidirectional relationships causes circular error

Tags: jackson, jhipster

I have a bidirectional OneToMany relationship between the entites Basket and ProductOrder.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "basket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<ProductOrder> products = new HashSet<>();
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("products")
private Basket basket;
```

When I add a new productOrder to the basket and call the update method on the basket. The productOrder is being created but gets no reference to the basket which results in the basket having no productOrders!

I tried setting the basket from the productOrder but then it ends in a endless circle and I get:

> ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

So my question is, how to handle bidirectional relationships in jhipster?

This is how I would like to update my basket:

**test-component.ts**

```
intoBasket(product, amount) {
    this.productOrder = new ProductOrder();
    this.productOrder.product = product;
    this.productOrder.amount = amount;
    this.basketService.find(+this.account.id).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Basket>) => {
        this.basket = res.body;
        this.productOrder.basket = this.basket;
        this.basket.products.push(this.productOrder);  
        this.basketService.update(this.basket).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Basket>) => {
        console.log("test");
        });  
    });      
}
```

thank you!

**Update**

I moved some logic from the frontend to the backend:

**BasketService.java**

```
public Basket save(Basket basket) {
    log.debug("Request to save Basket : {}", basket);
    log.info(basket.getProducts().toString());
    basket.getProducts().stream().forEach(p -> p.setBasket(basket));

    return basketRepository.save(basket);
}
```

this saves the ProductOrders properly with a reference to the Basket. But When I try to log the products from the basket in the frontend I get null which is odd because the method

```
 this.basketService.update(this.basket).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Basket>) => {
    console.log(res.body.products);
    });
```

actually returns the basket filled with the new product. But it doesn't seem to save it because when I request that specific basket "/baskets/39" the response is missing the products:

> {id: 39, totalPrice: 0, customerId: 39, products: null}

**Update 2**

okay, i restarted the product microservice which is responsible for these entities and now everything works fine. I didn't know I had to restart it but that's good to know I guess.

Comment: 1. You must set the basket of the productOrder. 2 the JSON problem has nothing to do with JPA which doesn't deal with JSON, doesn't care about JSON, and isn't designed to represent a JSON structure. So, use the appropriate JSON configuration/annotations to avoid serializing what shouldn't be serialized, or better, don't serialize entities to JSON in the first place. Design DTOs that match with the JSON structure you want to generate, and transform the entities to these DTOs.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. I realised this is more a question about JHipster and not JPA. JHipster generates everything for me. I just have to define the relationships beforehand so now I don't really know where I have to change something. Thanks anyways ( I also edited the tags )

Comment: You're putting your persistence logic in the frontend, in the Angular service, rather than in the backend where it belongs. Just send what needs to be sent, in a single request, to the server (i.e. a command containing the product, the amount and the account ID), and let the server create the ProductOrder and add it correctly to the basket. The frontend shouldn't have to know whether you're using JPA or not, unidirectional or bidirectional associations or not.

Comment: Consider using JHipster DTOs  option and learn more about Jackson annotations to customize JSON serialization. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Thanks. I moved some logic to the backend and updated my post. It works better now but still not quite! Thanks

Comment: As you have `@JsonIgnoreProperties("products")` it seems normal to have null for products when serialized in JSON.

Comment: this wasn't the problem. JsonIgnore actually ignores the field and does not set it to null. I had to restart the microservice and now it works all good.